# Sorting mySQL Results By Column Values

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjlwg.png)

Referring to the table in the attached image "Example".

Our go kart racing club uses eCommerce software for online registration.  Each registration has a unique number in column *coCartID*.  Then all of the details of the registration (Driver Name, Kart #, etc etc) have equal status as options, so they all appear in the same column *coCartOption*, and are identified by the headings in the *coOptID* column.

I managed to display a sorted list of the most recent registrations:

```
$sql = "
SELECT coCartID, coOptGroup, coCartOption, coOptID
FROM cartoptions
WHERE coCartID > 2200 AND (coOptGroup = '*Driver Name:' OR coOptGroup = '*1st Class - $85:' OR coOptGroup = '1st Class - $100:' OR coOptGroup = '*1st Class Kart #:' OR coOptGroup = '1st Transponder #:' OR coOptGroup = '2nd Class - $25:' OR coOptGroup = '2nd Class Kart #:' OR coOptGroup = '2nd Transponder #:')
ORDER BY coCartID ASC, coOptID DESC
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row["coOptGroup"] . $row["coCartOption"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

With the above code, the information is displayed with breaks in between each line, and I can only control the order by setting *coOptID* as ascending or descending:

**Kari Hillwig

33

Sr. World Formula

Arman Cornell

9193664

100cc Master

99

Fred Blauvelt

Sr. World Formula

77**

QUESTION 1: How to combine all entries with the same coCartID and display in a single row.  I've spent several frustrating hours with fetch_assoc, fetch_array, & fetch_row, but no matter what I can't get the break placed in the correct location:

**Kari Hillwig, Sr. World Formula, 33 

Arman Cornell, 100cc Master, 99, 9193664

Fred Blauvelt, Sr. World Formula, 77**

QUESTION 2:  Aside from ASC or DESC, is it possible to sort the *coOptID* data in a specific order?  (If so I can then display the corresponding *coCartOption* data in the same order).

Thank You in advance,

Comment: *coOptID data in a specific order* How exactly you want to order your result set using this attribute ?

Comment: How do you want coOptID sorted?

Comment: Sorry it's probably more clear to sort by the names as shown in *coOptGroup*:  Driver Name, 1st Class, 1st Class Kart #, 1st Transponder #, 2nd Class, 2nd Class Kart #, 2nd Transponder #  .  Pit Pass and Rent Transponder do not need to be displayed, but can be.

Comment: @seventh-gear are these keys `Driver Name, 1st Class ...` fixed or there can be more in future ?

Comment: They are Option categories so it's possible to add an infinite number, however it wouldn't be a regular occurrence, the query could be reconfigured each time if necessary.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following query to get data row wise for each `coCartID` for fixed no. of `coOptGroup`(s)

```
SELECT coCartID,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup = '*Driver Name:' THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) DriverName,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup IN('*1st Class - $85:','1st Class - $100:' ) THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 1stClass,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup = '*1st Class Kart #:' THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 1stClassKart,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup = '1st Transponder #:' THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 1stClassTransponder,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup ='2nd Class - $25:'  THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 2ndClass,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup = '2nd Class Kart #:' THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 2ndClassKart,
MAX(CASE WHEN coOptGroup = '2nd Transponder #:' THEN coCartOption ELSE NULL END) 2ndClassTransponder
FROM cartoptions
WHERE coCartID > 2200
AND (coOptGroup = '*Driver Name:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '*1st Class - $85:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '1st Class - $100:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '*1st Class Kart #:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '1st Transponder #:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '2nd Class - $25:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '2nd Class Kart #:' 
    OR coOptGroup = '2nd Transponder #:'
)
GROUP BY coCartID
ORDER BY coCartID ASC
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/YSQG30984)

when you execute above query you will all the values related to single `coCartID` in `$row` like `$row["DriverName"]` ,`$row['1stClass']` ... in each loop iteration

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid   Thank You...  I am following your SQL but I'm a bit confused on what to Echo to display correctly.

Comment: @seventh-gear i have updated my answer hope it make sense

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid -- Ah, I understand now... This solution works perfectly on the first try.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `ORDER BY` and `SEPARATOR` parameters, and an `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/141e5f/6

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coCartOption
ORDER BY
    FIELD (coOptGroup,
           '*Driver Name:',
           '*1st Class - $85:',
           '1st Class - $100:',
           '*1st Class Kart #:',
           '1st Transponder #:',
           '2nd Class - $25:',
           '2nd Class Kart #:',
           '2nd Transponder #:')
    SEPARATOR ', ') AS csv
FROM cartoptions
WHERE coCartID>2200 AND 
      coCartOption!='(N/A)' AND
      coOptGroup IN (
          '*Driver Name:',
          '*1st Class - $85:',
          '1st Class - $100:',
          '*1st Class Kart #:',
          '1st Transponder #:',
          '2nd Class - $25:',
          '2nd Class Kart #:',
          '2nd Transponder #:')
GROUP BY coCartID
ORDER BY coCartID
```

This query should be fairly simple to understand and update in the future.

See my demo link for the clean three-row, single-column resultset.